# CSRF Conflict Creating Form and Logout Errors

Tags: error, logout, csrf

The contact form on a site I am currently developing was displaying an error when trying to submit and says the *form has expired*.

Based on feedback I found in various forums, the workaround I have found was to turn off CSRF protection through the config file using this code:

```
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';
```

This fixes the form, but creates another bug that prevents users from being able to log out, causing this error: *You are not authorized to perform this action.*

Does anyone have a solution that will fix both problems?

Comment: You just should disable the csrf protection in very specific situations, like a server based cache. These forms being rejected are on CP or on front end?

Comment: The form that is giving me the error is a contact form on the front end. I remember setting a CSRF setting in the database in the past, but I cannot find where this was.

Comment: Is the date and time of the server set right? Does the [`{current_time}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-time) give you the right time?

Comment: The data is correct, and the time is showing up as Eastern time zone (I am in Mountain time zone.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that seems to be working. Here are the details in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

I kept the code in the config.php file that turns off CSRF protection:

```
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';
```

Then to fix the issue with logout failing, I implemented an edit suggested by Robin Sowell on the Ellis Lab forum. The edit is in the file "system/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member_auth.php":

Find this code in that file:

```
if ($token != CSRF_TOKEN)
{
```

and change to:

```
if ( ! bool_config_item('disable_csrf_protection') && $token != CSRF_TOKEN)
{
```

Comment: Just circling back for any new readers- the inability to logout with csrf disabled was indeed a bug fixed in 2.8.2.  

But Robson's right- csrf should only be disabled for testing and shouldn't be a long term solution to a secure form problem.